# How can I activate multiple buttons on one page using JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to build a page where a user can select multiple items by clicking on a button. I already used focus and active classes to make the buttons change appearance but with my current code I can only activate one single button. I'm looking for code that enables a user to activate multiple buttons.

**HTML**

```
<button class="btn btn-1">
    button 1
</button>

<button class="btn btn-1">
    button 2
</button>

<button class="btn btn-1">
    button 3
</button>

<button class="btn btn-1">
    button 4
</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.btn:hover {
  background-color: rgba(52, 152, 219,0.6);
}

.btn:focus {
  background-color: rgba(52, 152, 219,0.6);
}

.btn:active, .btn:visited {
  background-color: rgba(52, 152, 219,0.6);
}

.active {
  background-color: rgba(52, 152, 219,0.6); 
}
```

This is the jQuery code I have been using to try and add a permanent active class to those buttons that have been clicked. This is not working yet.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.btn').click(function() { 
        $('.btn').addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `$(this)` to add `active` class to the clicked button

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.btn').click(function() { 
       $(this).addClass('active');// use this here
    });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ledlogic/um01c513/)

**EDIT** - as suggested by @Regent, you can use toggleClass to active and deactive on button click, use below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
     $('.btn').click(function() { 
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
 });
```

**[Demo for toggleClass](http://jsfiddle.net/um01c513/5/)**
**Note** - here I have commented `.btn:focus` css class because on second click button looks active as it is focused.

Comment: And just to mention: if you want to be able to deactivate button clicking again on it, you can use `toggleClass` instead of `addClass`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('.btn').click(function() { 
    $('.btn').toggleClass('active');
});
});
```

I think if you use "this" the action only takes effect in the button you are clicking itself.